# xcode 4 dismissModalViewControllerAnimated

Tags: xcode4

In my app,I switch value between views [dismissModalViewControllerAnimated].
I have one text and one button in the first viewcontroller.When i press button if text empty,gives on alert view.
If text full,to calculate the second view Label.it's works.
But when i mov from the first viewcontroller to the second viewcontroller,the value of the text is written in before on passing.
So, when i press back and press button second time,I see correct value in Label.
Can i help me please

**FirstViewController.m**

```
(IBAction)go:(id)sender {
if ([aText.text length]>0)
    {

        SecondViewController *lvc =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];
        [self presentModalViewController:lvc animated:YES];

    }

    else {
        UIAlertView *message =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Please enter value" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
(IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}
```

---

value of the variable my formul: `[atext floatvalue] * 2` while the text empty,and i input text 10 and after press button Label is NAN press back button, goto first view controller again press GO button Label is 20

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I can't understand what you're trying to do (and I've tried!).

If you want to pass a value from a ViewController to another, you should do something like this:

```
SecondViewController *lvc =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];
lvc.value = yourValue;
[self presentModalViewController:lvc animated:YES];
```

Comment: value of the variable
my formul:
[atext floatvalue] * 2
while the text empty,and i input text 10 
and after press button Label is NAN
press back button, goto first view controller
again press GO button
Label is 20